# Make { and } ignore lines containing only whitespace

Tags: vim

When you navigate by paragraph in vim using { and } it skips lines that contain nothing but whitespace though they are otherwise 'blank'.

How can I convince vim to treat "whitespace only" lines as paragraph breaks so { and } will jump to them?

Comment: Is there a bug report for this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a modified version that handles counts correctly:

```
function! ParagraphMove(delta, visual, count)
    normal m'
    normal |
    if a:visual
        normal gv
    endif

    if a:count == 0
        let limit = 1
    else
        let limit = a:count
    endif

    let i = 0
    while i < limit
        if a:delta > 0
            " first whitespace-only line following a non-whitespace character           
            let pos1 = search("\\S", "W")
            let pos2 = search("^\\s*$", "W")
            if pos1 == 0 || pos2 == 0
                let pos = search("\\%$", "W")
            endif
        elseif a:delta < 0
            " first whitespace-only line preceding a non-whitespace character           
            let pos1 = search("\\S", "bW")
            let pos2 = search("^\\s*$", "bW")
            if pos1 == 0 || pos2 == 0
                let pos = search("\\%^", "bW")
            endif
        endif
        let i += 1
    endwhile
    normal |
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> } :<C-U>call ParagraphMove( 1, 0, v:count)<CR>
onoremap <silent> } :<C-U>call ParagraphMove( 1, 0, v:count)<CR>
" vnoremap <silent> } :<C-U>call ParagraphMove( 1, 1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> { :<C-U>call ParagraphMove(-1, 0, v:count)<CR>
onoremap <silent> { :<C-U>call ParagraphMove(-1, 0, v:count)<CR>
" vnoremap <silent> { :<C-U>call ParagraphMove(-1, 1)<CR>
```

Comment: Visual mode (and everything else) works in [`https://github.com/dbakker/vim-paragraph-motion`](https://github.com/dbakker/vim-paragraph-motion)

Answer (score 3):

As said before, if you run `:help paragraph` you will see that lines with whitespace are not treated as a boundary.

In the mean time there are two plugin projects which could help:

- [Improved paragraph motion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3952) (mirrored as https://github.com/vim-scripts/Improved-paragraph-motion)
- [Vim Paragraph Motion](https://github.com/dbakker/vim-paragraph-motion) based on the code in the other answers.

---

If you use Pathogen, simply download from one of the sites mentioned above.

If you use Vundle, put one of the following in your `.vimrc`:

- Improved paragraph motion:

  ```
  Bundle 'vim-scripts/Improved-paragraph-motion'
  ```
- Vim Paragraph Motion:

  ```
  Bundle 'dbakker/vim-paragraph-motion'
  ```

Run `:BundleInstall` after a reboot and the `{` `}` motions should stop on lines containing whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that's bothered me for a long time.  Probably the "right" solution would be to submit a patch to vim itself that would allow you to customize paragraph boundaries with a regex (like :set paragraphs, but actually useful).

In the meantime, I've made a function and a couple of mappings that almost do the right thing:

```
function! ParagraphMove(delta, visual)
    normal m'
    normal |
    if a:visual
        normal gv
    endif

    if a:delta > 0
        " first whitespace-only line following a non-whitespace character
        let pos1 = search("\\S", "W")
        let pos2 = search("^\\s*$", "W")
        if pos1 == 0 || pos2 == 0
            let pos = search("\\%$", "W")
        endif
    elseif a:delta < 0
        " first whitespace-only line preceding a non-whitespace character
        let pos1 = search("\\S", "bW")
        let pos2 = search("^\\s*$", "bW")
        if pos1 == 0 || pos2 == 0
            let pos = search("\\%^", "bW")
        endif
    endif
    normal |
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> } :call ParagraphMove( 1, 0)<CR>
onoremap <silent> } :call ParagraphMove( 1, 0)<CR>
" vnoremap <silent> } :call ParagraphMove( 1, 1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> { :call ParagraphMove(-1, 0)<CR>
onoremap <silent> { :call ParagraphMove(-1, 0)<CR>
" vnoremap <silent> { :call ParagraphMove(-1, 1)<CR>
```

This doesn't correctly handle counts like '4}' or visual mode correctly (uncomment the vnoremap lines at your peril), but seems ok for things like not clobbering the current search pattern and not flickering.  Also, 'd}', 'y}', etc. seem to work ok.  If anyone has ideas for making counts work or fixing visual mode, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The { and } commands move by "paragraph", and vim's documentation (see `:help paragraph`) says:

> Note that a blank line (only
>   containing white space) is NOT a
>   paragraph boundary.

So the only way you can do this would be to remap { and }.
Something like:

```
nmap { ?^\\s*$<CR>
nmap } /^\\s*$<CR>
```

could work, but you may want to adjust this so it doesn't alter your search history.

Comment: This is a decent start, but has a few problems... The ones which immediately come to mind: visual mode, clobbering search history, properly unsetting/resetting `hlsearch`, the slight blink of the cursor as it flicks to the command bar (minor, yes, but still annoying).

Comment: Anyway, I think it's a good solution... And, if nothing else turns up, it may be the only solution (in which case, a bit of Vim scripting might make the issues less painful).

Answer (score 0):

I never have a legitimate need for whitespace only lines so I solved this "problem" by adding the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
" Highlight spaces at the end of lines.
highlight link localWhitespaceError Error
au Syntax * syn match localWhitespaceError /\(\zs\%#\|\s\)\+$/ display

" Remove end of line white space.
noremap <Leader>r ma:%s/\s\+$//e<CR>`a
```

So then if <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd> skips whitespace only lines I use my mapping to remove it and try again.

Comment: Explanation here: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces

Comment: Well, I say "explanation", but that is being generous. I defy anyone to explain it.

Comment: some formats, notable git diffs, use white-space (sometimes trailing) that is significant

Answer (score 0):

I finally caved and did something similar to
*eremite*. I previously had
`Z` mapped to `{gq}`, which reformats text from last
blank line to the next blank line. If lines
containing only spaces are not recognized as
boundaries, it can destroy a lot of intricate code
structures, and days of work. Undo is not an
option if I've switched buffers a few times using
`<C-^>`.

I leveraged a custom command `command! Trim execute "normal \<S-m>" | % s=\s*$== | execute "normal \<C-o>z.\<C-o>" | set nohlsearch` to
"Trim" all trailing spaces in my file. I have
`expandtab` enabled so I only ever have spaces, not
tabs. But it's easy enough to delete all trailing
space using `\_s` instead of `\s`. My new `Z`
command is `` nmap Z mq:Trim<CR>`q{gq}`q ``. I use
marker `q` to store my current cursor position,
then use  `` `q `` to return to it after the
reformatting.