# vimtex: force } and { not to skip empty lines

Tags: vim, latex, keyboard-shortcuts, vim-plugin

When I use `}` and `{`, vimtex+vim jumps somewhat randomly in the document, skipping several empty lines. See below.

*How to restore the default vim behaviour not to skip the empty lines?*

[image]

Comment: Are these lines really empty or do they contain characters you just do not see?

Comment: @rkta that solved it. unbelievable. of course, the next question is how not to skip the visually empty lines, but that is a different question. put your comment as an answer and I will accept it. thanks!

Comment: regarding "visually empty" lines a plugin like https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3952 can help. or https://github.com/dbakker/vim-paragraph-motion

Comment: There is no need for plugins, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

The fact that the skipping happens pretty randomly indicates that the empty lines are not really empty. They contain a whitespace or other special characters.

Move the cursor to these 'empty' lines and press `$` to see if they are really empty.

---

### How to avoid such problems:

<sup>(Yes, others had your problem too.)</sup>

**Make vim show whitespace characters**
Vim has a way to show these characters. Use `set list` and define `listchars`. From the vim help for listchars:

> ```
>     Strings to use in 'list' mode and for the :list command.  It is a
>     comma separated list of string settings. 
>     [...]
>                                                     lcs-space
>       space:c       Character to show for a space.  When omitted, spaces
>                     are left blank.
>                                                     lcs-trail
>       trail:c       Character to show for trailing spaces.  When omitted,
>                     trailing spaces are blank.  Overrides the "space"
>                     setting for trailing spaces.
> ```

See `:help :list` and `:help listchars` for more information.

---

**Highlight trailing whitespace**
I find it quite annoying to always have a character displayed for any space and my eyes are too bad to see a little dot at the end of a line (for trailing spaces). Therefore I use a highlight group to show all trailing whitespace characters:

```
" Show trailing whitespace
    highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red       " define highlight group                      
    match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/               " define pattern
    autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/         " apply match to all buffers
    autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/  " don't match while in insert 
    autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
    autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()                   " It's good for the RAM
```

---

**Auto-remove trailing whitespace**
There is also a way to automagically delete those characters when writing the buffer -- but there are some caveats (think of markdown's double trailing whitespace for line breaks).

[Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces) has a good explanation.

The simplest (but maybe not the best) solution is to add

```
 autocmd BufWritePre * %s/\s\+$//e
```

to your `.vimrc` or to the corresponding `ftplugin` files.
I personally have a function in my `vimrc` and disable it for file types, where I don't want/need it.

---

You may also be interested in [Make { and } ignore lines containing only whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853025/make-and-ignore-lines-containing-only-whitespace)

---

<sub>*Disclaimer*

There might be characters that are not whitespace, but are also not shown by vim by default. I never had this problem, but what I said under 'Short Answer' still does apply.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Find if there are any mappings for `}` using

```
:map }
```

Now, you can unmap any mappings you find with

```
:unmap }
```

If you wanna put this in your `.vimrc`, I'd suggest doing it in the after directory for that plugin.

like  `~/.vim/after/plugin`

Comment: The comment by @rkta was correct --- the lines were empty only visually, but in reality they had spaces. Yet, your answer is helpful: there were no special mappings, which would probably lead me to discover those space symbols. So, thank you for your answer!